# Can I trigger a file upload from an element contained within a Vue component with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, cypress

With Cypress, I'm unable to click a dropzone to upload a file.  It feels like there is something preventing the click event from happening.  Am I clicking the wrong element?

It works manually.  (I don't know which specific element is actually recieving the click though)
I've tried `{ force: true }` - Cypress shows a successful click here but nothing happens.

[image]
I've tried parent and child elements.
I've tried the `Cypress.$` command to bypass the `cy` wrapper.

```js
// spec code
it.only('has clickable area for upload', () => {
    cy.visit('#bulkPolicyOnboarding')
      .get('#BulkPolicyOnboardingStartup')
      .find('.file-upload')
      .find('input[type=file]')
      .click({ force: true })
  })
```

```html
// component code
<template>
    <section id="widget-grid" v-show="IsShown === true">
        <div>
            <div class="row">
                <article class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-darken" data-widget-sortable="false" data-widget-togglebutton="true" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-fullscreenbutton="false" data-widget-colorbutton="true" data-widget-deletebutton="false">
                        <header>
                            <h2>Add Document</h2>
                        </header>

                        <div>
                            <div class="widget-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <file-upload v-model="file"></file-upload>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br />

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
                                        <a class="btn btn-labeled btn-info" v-on:click="UploadFileToServer"><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Upload File</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

```html
// nested component (the one I'm trying to click?)
<template>
  <div class="file-upload">
    <input type="file" style="display: none;" @change="FileChanged" />
    <div
      class="uploader"
      @click="OpenFile"
      @dragover="DragOver"
      @dragenter="DragEnter"
      @dragleave="DragLeave"
      @drop="DropFile"
    >
      <span class="instructions">click to select, or drag and drop a file</span>
      <label
        class="selected-file"
        style="font-size: 1em;"
        v-html="selectedFile"
      ></label>
      <span class="x" v-show="HasFile()" @click="RemoveFile">&#10006;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm expecting on click (like in manual testing), that the event would fire and the window pops up for file select -- but nothing happens on click in Cypress.

UPDATE:
Per  Recep Karadas, I've tried the `.uploader` selector, but same result:

[image]

Comment: I think it's the wrong element. You are clicking the `<input type="file" style="display: none;" @change="FileChanged" />` element. Please change `find('input[type=file]')` to `find('.uploader')` and try again.

Comment: This may work for you and save you some code.  https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload

Comment: @Brendan ty, I did make a quick attempt at using ```cypress-file-upload```, but I'm not sure I fully understand how it works -- I was getting some errors

Comment: I haven't used it yet so I can't help unfortunately, just recently found it and am planning to swap out our custom commands for that to offload some support to an open source solution.